# How to get an array of object properties in an array?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I have a class Person:

```
@interface Person : NSObject
{
    NSInteger *_age
    NSString *_name;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSInteger *age;   
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@end
```

Then I have a NSArray of Persons:

```
Person *personA;
Person *personB;
allPersons = @[personA, personB];
```

How do I get an array of all names:

```
allPersonNames = @[Max, Bob];
```

Other than to loop through all objects and addObject the name property to a NSMutableArray, is that possible with a single line of code?

Thanks

Comment: Please log your 'array' as your description of the data structure doesn't look right / valid. You appear to be confusing arrays and dictionaries...

Comment: Thanks Wain, edited the example above.

Comment: Not an array of dictionaries, but the answer from @robmayoff applies anyway

Comment: Note that it is wrong to declare `NSInteger *` as strong property (as NSInteger is non-object plain data type like int). You probably do not need pointer at all and it should say `...,assign) NSInteger age;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an array of names using Key-Value Coding, like this:

```
NSArray *names = [allPersons valueForKey:@"name"];
```

This is documented in the last paragraph of [section “Getting Attribute Values Using Key-Value Coding” of the *Key-Value Coding Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/BasicPrinciples.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002170-178726):

> When a value is returned for a key path that contains a key for a to-many property, and that key is not the last key in the path, the returned value is a collection containing all the values for the keys to the right of the to-many key. For example, requesting the value of the key path `transactions.payee` returns an array containing all the payee objects, for all the transactions. This also works for multiple arrays in the key path. The key path `accounts.transactions.payee` would return an array with all the payee objects, for all the transactions, in all the accounts.